# How to get userId for Google Fit API?

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-apis-explorer, google-people-api, google-fit-api

How to get userId for getting the activity data of the user from google fit API.
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/dataSources/dataSourceId`
I can able to get my data by replacing userId with me but I want to create an application for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/get), the only supported value for the user id is "me".

The identity of the user that "me" refers to is conveyed by the OAuth token you pass with your request.

If you want to access the data for a user, they will need to grant an OAuth token to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, After so many tries now I'm able to fetch data through POSTMAN too but I'm using access token generated on Oauth 2.0 playground. How can I generate an access token through my app, however, I've registered my application on google console. I'm working with Google APIs for the first time please help!.

Comment: I'm creating an application where I need to get the fitness data of the user who has downloaded my application. How I can get an OAuth token for that user.